# Console freezes when trying to print all Nodes of a chain in order

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nodes

I've been trying to deal with this problem for two days now, asked a few of my classmates and no one was able to find the problem, any help would be appreciated as this project is due tomorrow morning.

So the instructions for the code are to build three classes:
Book - has name and author.
Author - has name and node chain of type book (list of books made by the author).
Library - has two node chains, one of type book (contains all library books) and one of type author (contains all authors that have their books in library).

Then we need to build this menu:

```
1 -- Add book to library
2 -- Print all books
3 -- Print all authors
4 -- Print books of author
5 -- Get Number of Book
6 -- Exit the program
```

And the problem is with 2 - "print all books"

To print all books, I made a function in Library called PrintBooks which is basically a toString() for the LibraryBooks node chain:

```
public string PrintBooks()
    {
        string str = "";
        Node<Book> search = LibraryBooks;
        while (search != null)
        {
            str = str + search.GetInfo().GetName() + " " + search.GetInfo().GetAuthor() + " -> ";
            search = search.GetNext();
        }
        return str;
    }
```

And this is how I'm using it in Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 0;
        Node<Book> LibraryBooks = new Node<Book>(null);
        Node<Author> LibraryAuthors = new Node<Author>(null);
        Library library = new Library(LibraryBooks, LibraryAuthors);
        Console.WriteLine("1 -- Add book to library");
        Console.WriteLine("2 -- Print all books");
        Console.WriteLine("3 -- Print all authors");
        Console.WriteLine("4 -- Print books of author");
        Console.WriteLine("5 -- Get Number of Book");
        Console.WriteLine("6 -- Exit the program");

        while (x != 6) //6 -- Exit the program
        {
            x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (x == 1) //1 -- Add book to librarybooks
            {
                string name=null, author=null;

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Book's Name");
                name = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Book's Author's Name");
                author = Console.ReadLine();

                Book book = new Book(name, author);
                library.AddBook(book);

                Console.WriteLine("1 -- Add book to library");
                Console.WriteLine("2 -- Print all books");
                Console.WriteLine("3 -- Print all authors");
                Console.WriteLine("4 -- Print books of author");
                Console.WriteLine("5 -- Get Number of Book");
                Console.WriteLine("6 -- Exit the program");

            }
            if (x == 2) //2 -- Print all books
            {
                string debug = ""; 
                debug = library.PrintBooks();
                Console.WriteLine(debug);

                Console.WriteLine("1 -- Add book to library");
                Console.WriteLine("2 -- Print all books");
                Console.WriteLine("3 -- Print all authors");
                Console.WriteLine("4 -- Print books of author"); 
                Console.WriteLine("5 -- Get Number of Book");
                Console.WriteLine("6 -- Exit the program");

            }
```

Also, AddBook which is used to add the book to LibraryBooks inside Library, is a function in Library:

```
public void AddBook(Book book)
    {
        if (LibraryBooks == null)
        {
            LibraryBooks.SetInfo(book);
            LibraryBooks.SetNext(null);
        }
        else
        {
            LibraryBooks.SetNext(LibraryBooks);
            LibraryBooks.SetInfo(book);
        }
```

Now, the error occurs when I try to use PrintBooks, the console always freezes when executing this line:

```
debug = library.PrintBooks();
```

So I thought the problem was with PrintBooks but my classmates used it almost exactly the same and it worked for them, maybe the printbooks doesn't actually use the same LibraryBooks as the one to which the books in AddBook were added to? 
As you can see, this code isn't too complicated, its just that I'm new to it, so I have trouble debugging errors that don't give me an error message.

I will be more than happy to add any other part of the project that is needed to this post, to solve this.

Thank you for taking the time to read this

Edit: Full code below to replicate error, there are a lot of temporary parts that you can just ignore, the parts that I uploaded below are the related ones

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HelloEran
{
class Node<T>
{
    private T info;
    private Node<T> next;
    public Node(T info)
    {
        this.info = info;
        this.next = null;
    }
    public Node(T info, Node<T> next)
    {
        this.info = info;
        this.next = next;
    }
    public T GetInfo()
    {
        return info;
    }
    public Node<T> GetNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
    public void SetInfo(T info)
    {
        this.info = info;
    }
    public void SetNext(Node<T> next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }
    public int GetSize()
    {
        Node<T> pos = this;
        int count = 0;

        while (pos != null)
        {
            count++;
            pos = pos.GetNext();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public String ToString()
    {
        return this.info.ToString();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int id = 1;
        Node<Book> LibraryBooks = new Node<Book>(null);
        Node<Author> LibraryAuthors = new Node<Author>(null);
        Library library = new Library(LibraryBooks, LibraryAuthors);
        Console.WriteLine("1 -- Add book to library");
        Console.WriteLine("2 -- Print all books");
        Console.WriteLine("3 -- Print all authors");
        Console.WriteLine("4 -- Print books of author");
        Console.WriteLine("5 -- Get Number of Book");
        Console.WriteLine("6 -- Exit the program");

        while (x != 6) //6 -- Exit the program
        {
            x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (x == 1) //1 -- Add book to library
            {
                string name=null, author=null;

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Book's Name");
                name = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Book's Author's Name");
                author = Console.ReadLine();

                Book book = new Book(name, author, id);

                library.AddBook(book);

                id++;
                Console.WriteLine("1 -- Add book to library");
                Console.WriteLine("2 -- Print all books");
                Console.WriteLine("3 -- Print all authors");
                Console.WriteLine("4 -- Print books of author");
                Console.WriteLine("5 -- Get Number of Book");
                Console.WriteLine("6 -- Exit the program");

            }
            if (x == 2) //2 -- Print all books
            {
                string debug = ""; 
                debug = library.PrintBooks();
                Console.WriteLine(debug);

                Console.WriteLine("1 -- Add book to library");
                Console.WriteLine("2 -- Print all books");
                Console.WriteLine("3 -- Print all authors");
                Console.WriteLine("4 -- Print books of author"); 
                Console.WriteLine("5 -- Get Number of Book");
                Console.WriteLine("6 -- Exit the program");

            }
            if (x == 3) //3-- Print all authors
            {

            }
            if (x == 4) //4-- Print books of author
            {

            }
            if (x == 5) //5-- Get Number of Book
            {
                string numname = null, numauthor = null;
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Book's Name");
                numname = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Book's Author's Name");
                numauthor = Console.ReadLine();

                library.Idbook(numname, numauthor);

            }
        }
    }
}
class Book
{
    private string author, name;
    private int id;

    public Book(string name, string author,int id)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
    }
    public string GetAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }
    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public int Getid()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void Setid(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public string ToString()
    {
        return "bookID : " + id + " , BookName : " + name + " Author'sName : " + author;
    }
}
class Author
{
    private string name;
    private Node<Book> books;

    public Author(string name, Node<Book> books)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.books = books;
    }
    public Node<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        return books;
    }
    public string PrintAuthorsBooks()
    {
        string str = "";
        return str;
    }

}
class Library
{
    private Node<Book> LibraryBooks;
    private Node<Author> LibraryAuthors;

    public Library(Node<Book> LibraryBooks, Node<Author> LibraryAuthors)
    {
        this.LibraryBooks = LibraryBooks;
        this.LibraryAuthors = LibraryAuthors;
    }
    public Node<Book> GetLibraryBooks()
    {
        return LibraryBooks;
    }
    public Node<Author> GetLibraryAuthors()
    {
        return LibraryAuthors;
    }

    public void AddBook(Book book)
    {
        if (LibraryBooks == null)
        {
            LibraryBooks.SetInfo(book);
            LibraryBooks.SetNext(null);
        }
        else
        {
            LibraryBooks.SetNext(LibraryBooks);
            LibraryBooks.SetInfo(book);
        }
    }
    public void AddAuthor(Author author)
    {
        if (LibraryAuthors.GetInfo() == null)
        {
            LibraryAuthors.SetInfo(author);
            LibraryAuthors.SetNext(null);
        }
        else
        {
            LibraryAuthors.SetInfo(author);
            LibraryAuthors.SetNext(LibraryAuthors);
        }
    }
    public string PrintBooks()
    {
        string str = "";
        Node<Book> search = this.LibraryBooks;
        while (search.GetInfo() != null)
        {
            str = str + search.GetInfo().GetName() + " " + search.GetInfo().GetAuthor() + " -> ";
            search = search.GetNext();
        }
        return str;
    }
    public void Idbook(string name, string author)
    {

        Node<Book> temp = this.LibraryBooks;
        int l = temp.GetSize();
        bool exist = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            if (temp.GetInfo().GetName() == name && temp.GetInfo().GetAuthor() == author)
            {
                exist = true;
                Console.WriteLine("The ID of this book is " + temp.GetInfo().Getid());
            }
            temp = temp.GetNext();
        }

        if (exist == false)
            Console.WriteLine("This book does not exist in the library");

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a debugging problem.  Step through the code line by line as it runs and inspect the values.  Chances are, GetNext is never returning null.

Comment: Have a very close look at AddBook...

Comment: LarsTech - You're right, it's stuck on the while loop. But why doesn't it return null?
Klaus - having the SetNext Before the SetInfo is on purpose, my teacher told us to do it and didn't explain why.

Comment: You didn't show the GetNext code so we don't know.  It would be nice to see the SetNext code, too, since the way you call it in the AddBook method just looks weird.

Comment: GetNext is just 
public Node<T> GetNext()
            {
                return next;
            }
Thought it was standard

Comment: It's hard to help if you don't post the code that we can use to duplicate the problem.

Comment: You're right, full code added in edit below post

Comment: When you add a book, you are setting "next" to that book.  You might want to review that.